# Java date format different results

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I am looking to understand why this code is giving me different results.

I want to format `2022-10-12T00:00:00.000Z` into `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

- Result when I run it online in Java IDE: `2022-10-12`
- But on my own computer the result is: `2022-10-11`

```
String date = "2022-10-12T00:00:00.000Z";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(date);
Instant i = Instant.from(ta);
Date d = Date.from(i);
dateFormat.format(d);
```

Comment: Have you stored formated date returned by "dateFormat.format(d)... as it is not appearing in the code you have posted..?   I checked it by String sDate = dateFormat.format(d); and it is giving correct result

Comment: It is never the same date in all time zones. In which time zone do you want the date? Your string denotes a point in time at which it is 2022-10-11 on about half of the globe.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. You are already using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Just stick to that and do not mix outdated and modern.

Comment: You want something as simple as `Instant.parse(date).atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Yekaterinburg")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)`. This gives `2022-10-12` (as you said you wanted). Please supply your desired time zone. America/Matamoros, for example, yields `2022-10-11`. As it should.

Comment: Your online Java IDE probably uses UTC as its default time zone (it would be the only reasonable choice if used worldwide), and since your string is in UTC (denoted by the trailing `Z`), you get the date from the string, `2022-10-12` (as I said, in another time zone you may very well get another result).

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Louis Wasserman is correct. A couple of important points:

1. The ***java.util*** date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).
2. `SimpleDateFormat` does not have a way to specify a time-zone in the pattern. The way to specify a time-zone with `SimpleDateFormat` is by calling [`SimpleDateFormat#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)). Without setting time-zone explicitly, `SimpleDateFormat` uses the system time-zone. You could get the desired result had you done the following

```
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    dateFormat.format(d);
```

### The solution

> I want to format 2022-10-12T00:00:00.000Z into yyyy-MM-dd format

**Demo with java.time API**:

Since your date-time string is in UTC and you want to get just date part from the UTC date-time:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2022-10-12T00:00:00.000Z";

        // Parse the given text into an OffsetDateTime and format it
        String desiredString = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDate)
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);

        System.out.println(desiredString);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-10-12
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: A lot of good points. I might wish for a deeper treatment of the time zone issue which appears to be at the heart of the OP’s question. Because I am not convinced that it is clear to the asker which time zone they want or whether they want the UTC offset from the string (in this case `Z`, but it could be different in the next string). (On the other hand how to fix the `SimpleDateFormat` is superfluous since no one wants to use that class anyway. The OP is already demonstrating that they can use java.time.)

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your feedback. A couple of points: (1) The OP has mentioned, **I want to format 2022-10-12T00:00:00.000Z into yyyy-MM-dd format** and since this date-time string is in UTC, there is no confusion here that [s]he wants to get just date part from the UTC date-time. (2) Guiding how to fix the problem with `SimpleDateFormat` is not going to cause any harm as long as [s]he follows the advice mentioned in my previous point: **The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone.**

Answer (score 2):

If the online IDE is running in a different time zone than you, it might be 10-12 in one time zone and still 10-11 in another.  You have specified Z as the time zone of the input, but you have not specified the time zone used in formatting the date.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that `Date`/`SimpleDateFormat`  don’t support time zone.
You can try using the java.time package:

```
LocalDate.now()
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(LocalDate.now())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution. Using java.time (entirely) is an excellent idea. I also agree with you that the reason why the code presented gave different results online and locally is a time zone difference. You may want to emphasize this part of your answer more. You can edit the answer, and I encourage you to do that. Your code shows how to format a modern `LocalDate`, which is not all that the asker needs, but should still point in the right direction and be helpful.